# Display one-to-many relational result set from PDO query with joined table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, one-to-many

I'm trying to combine two mysql tables (the first table is for questions and the second table is for answers of those questions) in one php loop.

What I have is: I can display all the questions with only their first answer (the trouble is that every question has more than one answer).

Here is my code with the request and the loop:

```
<?php
$select = $baseblog->prepare('select questions.question,reponses.reponse from questions inner join reponses where questions.id=reponses.id-question and questions.categorie="countries and cities"');
$selecttt = $select->execute(array());
?>
<div class="questions">
    <?php  while ($select1 = $select->fetch()) {?>
        <article>
            <p class="pp"><?php echo $select1['question'] ?> ?</p>
               
            <p><?php echo $select1['reponse'] ?> </p>
        </article>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This question would probably benefit from including a dbfiddle demo link as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result set has something like

```
question1    answer1
question1    answer2
question1    answer3
question2    answer4
question2    answer5
question2    answer6
question2    answer7
```

This we will use to identify changes in questions column and only then add a question.

The Design will need some adjustments

```
<?php
$select = $baseblog->prepare('SELECTquestions.question,reponses.reponse 
                              FROM questions INNER  JOIN reponses 
                              ON questions.id=reponses.id-question 
                              WHERE questions.categorie="countries and cities"  ');
          $selecttt=$select->execute(array());
   ?>

      <div class="questions">
        <?php  $question = ''; 
         while ($select1=$select->fetch()) {?>
            <article>
                <p class="pp"  ><?php 
                                if ($question != $select1['question']) {
                                  echo $select1['question'];
                                  $question = $select1['question']; 
                                }
                                  ?> ?</p>
               
                <p><?php echo $select1['reponse'] ?> </p>
            </article>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no reason to prepare if no variables are being passed into the sql.  SQL keywords should be uppercased for readability.  I recommend writing the SQL on multiple lines to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Comment: yes , there is no need, but you can use it anyway and would keep it as it is also good training

Comment: to fix the problem that i mentioned before , i did 3 changes :
1- I changed the "id-question" to "idquestion" in the request and in the database (because , i think mysql doesn't accept "-"  ) .
2- I applied your remark .
3- I wrote the "?" in echo (because when i let it like before , it create a problem ) .

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I approach these, and if it's not the best way, I look forward to learning the best way from their answer.

I use 2 queries to get all the data. For this example, I'm not going to prepare the query since there are no user-created variables to protect from.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$questionsResult = $mysqli->query("select question, id from questions where categorie='countries and cities'");

$questions = [];
$ids = [];
// loop through to get the ids for our next query
while ($row = $questionsResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
    $questions[$row['id']]= $row['question'];
}
$questionsResult->free_result(); // save memory

// now get all responses at once and store them under their question ids
$responses = [];
if (count($ids>0) {
     $responsesResult = $mysqli->query("select * from responses where question_id IN (" . implode(",", $ids) . ")");


     while ($row = $responsesResult->fetch_assoc()) {
         if (!isset($responses[$row['question_id']])) $responses[$row['question_id']] = [];
         $responses[$row['question_id']][]= $row;
     }

     $responsesResult->free_result(); // save memory
}
// now you've got everythign ready to go


    <div class="questions">
     <?php  foreach ($questions as $id => $question) {?>
         <article>
             <p class="pp"  ><?php echo $question ?> ?</p>
           <?php if (!isset($responses[$id])) {?>
             <p> No responses found </p>
           <? } else {
             foreach ($responses[$id] as $response) {?>
              <p><?php echo $response['reponse'] ?> </p>
           <?php }
           }?>
         </article>
         <?php } ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: @mickmackusa - because I didn't QC my answer! Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PDO, I recommend the [FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP) flag to instantly set up a nested result set in PHP.

Untested Recommendation:

```
$sql = "SELECT q.question, r.reponse 
        FROM questions q
        INNER JOIN reponses r ON q.id = r.`id-question`
        WHERE q.categorie = 'countries and cities'";
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
if ($result) {
    echo '<div class="questions">';
    foreach ($result as $question => $responses) {
        printf(
            '<article>
                 <p class="pp">%s?</p>
                 <p>%s</p>
             </article>',
             $question,
             implode('</p><p>', array_column($responses, 'reponse'))
        );
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: @MARYEM Did you even entertain my refined technique?